# Regex in a String [Python]

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So, there is this string:

```
str= u'(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=broken)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.16.102.46)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(UR=A)(SERVICE_NAME=SPA1_HJY)))'
```

From which I have to extract the values of `HOST`, `PORT` and `SERVICE_NAME`.

I used the following regex for all three respectively:

1. `re_exp1 = re.search(r"HOST=\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+", str_utf)`
2. `re_exp2 = re.search(r"(PORT=[1-9][0-9]*)", str_utf)`
3. `re_exp3 = re.search(r"(SERVICE_NAME=\w+_\w+)", str_utf)`

And it gives me following output:

1. `HOST=172.16.102.46`
2. `PORT=1521`
3. `SERVICE_NAME=SPA1_HJY`

Of course, I can remove `"HOST=", "PORT=" and "SERVICE_NAME="` from the obtained results and be left with only values;

But is there a better a regex which I can use here which will give only the values?

Hope this makes sense. :-)

Comment: Are you sure you'll never have an `(ADRESSES=(ADDRESS=...)(ADDRESS=...)...` in your TNS which would make you have multiple occurrences of HOST and PORT? Because if that's the case, you can combine your three regexs in one and use capturing groups to get the specific informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookbehind in Python Regex to look for a pattern before the capture group.

An example pattern for your first regex could be:
"(?<=HOST=)(\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+)"

Where (?<=HOST=) is a positive lookbehind. There are also negative lookbehinds as well as positive and negative lookaheads.

A useful website I use to test regex patterns is:
https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all these informations appear only once and always in the same order, I would use a single regex as follows :

```
HOST=(?P<host>(?:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*PORT=(?P<port>\d+).*SERVICE_NAME=(?P<serviceName>\w+)
```

Note the following improvments :

- host search : the `.` are escaped, otherwise they'd match any character ; the `\w` is restricted to `\d` instead (you could also use `[\d.]+` to match the whole IP address more concisely)
- port search : since you're extracting rather than validating, I didn't bother with validating that the port didn't start with a `0` (which I'm not sure would pose a problem anyway)
- service name search : I didn't bother validating that the service name had a `_` in the middle for the same reason (note that `\w` matches underscores).
- the three informations are matched in one pass by the regex, which defines 3 named groups "host", "port" and "serviceName"

You can use the regex with `re.search(pattern, input)`, then access the 3 informations by using the `.group(groupName)` method on the resulting object :

```
patternStr = "HOST=(?P<host>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+).*PORT=(?P<port>\d+).*SERVICE_NAME=(?P<serviceName>\w+)"

result = re.search(patternStr, input)

if (result) :
    print("host : " + result.group("host"))
    print("port : " + result.group("port"))
    print("serviceName : " + result.group("serviceName"))
```

You can see it in action [here](https://ideone.com/X2OXnC).

Comment: @VishalKNair You're welcome ! You can accept this answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict comprehension in combination with

```
(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>[^()]+)
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>[^()]+)')

string = u'(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=broken)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.16.102.46)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(UR=A)(SERVICE_NAME=SPA1_HJY)))'

result = {m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(string)}
print(result['HOST'], result['PORT'], result['SERVICE_NAME'])
```

Which yields

```
172.16.102.46 1521 SPA1_HJY
```

See a demo for the regular expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cG2Bh1/1).

Comment: That looks perfect! Thanks for your time! :-)